# How do I insert a new row in my table where it will take the next primary key available

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to Postgres SQL and will really appreciate some help on this. I have a large dataset called actors, comprising of a primary key (nconst), the name of the actors, their birth and death year. I would like to insert a new row of an actor into this dataset, that will take the next nconst available.

Thus I ran my code

```
INSERT INTO actors (name, birth_year, death_year)
VALUES (‘Jo Jo Slim’ ,1962, NULL);
```

However, I got back an error saying null value in column, 'nconst' violates not-null constraint.

As the dataset is large, I am unable to know what is the next nconst available. Hence how do I go about adding this row of data and to tell Postgres SQL to just generate the next available nconst? Thank you very much.

Below is 1 row of my dataset.

```
nconst   | name | birth_year | death_year     
" nm0000001 ", "Miss Jerry " , " 1940" , "2000"
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table `actors`. **[edit]** your question, do **not** post code in comments

Answer (score 1):

Define the primary key as a `serial` value:

```
create table actors (
    actorid serial primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    . . .
);
```

Then insert into the table -- all columns except the id:

```
INSERT INTO actors (name, birth_year, death_year)
    VALUES ('Jo Jo Slim', 1962, NULL);
```

The value with be an integer, rather than a string.  But this is a good choice for a primary key.

I recommend naming the column something like `actorid`, so you know what it means.  `nconst` doesn't mean anything, at least to me.